# google instant search on lynx

Tags: lynx

Just curious, since google search uses a lot of JS and AJAX, would it ever be possible to make instant search work on a text browser like lynx?

if yes, what would it take?

Comment: Run a shell and try it. I belive it will not work without a JS engine

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suppose it would take adding JS support to lynx?  Last I check (and I admit, that was quite a few years ago), lynx didn't have even the beginning of JS support.

Answer (score 0):

You can still execute google searches from Lynx. The instant search and other javascript quietly degrages to "dumb" search mode.